# Absolute convergence of the Laurent series

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series, signal-processing, laurent-series, z-transform

Consider the power series (which is the Laurent series around $z_0 = 0)$  $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}a_nz^{-n} \tag{1}$$ where $z \in \mathbb{C}$. It's known that the ROC (region of convergence) of $(1)$ is an annulus $r\lt|z|\lt R$ and maybe some of the boundary points. In the signal processing, we usually define the ROC as the set of points for which $(1)$ converges absolutely. I think this definition, at most misses some of the boundary points of the original ROC. For example, take $$a_n = \begin{cases}\frac{1}{n}, n\ge1 \\ 0 , n\le 0\end{cases}$$ Easily, it can be shown that the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{z^{-n}}{n}$$ converges absolutely for $|z|\gt 1$ and converges conditionally for $z = -1$. Also it diverges for $|z|\lt1$. So the difference between two ROCs is the circle $|z|=1$. Is it possible to prove this statement in general? Or is it possible to find examples such that the absolute convergence criterion misses other points as well (in addition to the boundary)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible. The series will always converge absolutely in the interior of the annulus and diverge outside. Only on the boundary you can have a more complex behavior. Such is the nature of power series. Check any Complex Analysis book for the proof.

Comment: Indeed, this follows from the analogous statement for power series, since the Laurent series is the sum of a power series in $z$ and a power series in $z^{-1}$.

Comment: Convergence is also uniform in any compact subset of the annulus of convergence.

Comment: Thanks. So the difference between ROCs (if there is any) should be the boundary points, right?

Comment: Right. Those are the only points where convergence depends on more subtle properties of your specific series.